# String usage as TextView ID

Tags: android, textview

I would like to generate a random string(with some rules), than use it as a textview id. For example I would like to use settext with this string.
Purpose: I should select a textview randomly, than set its text to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there are different kinds of way to achieve this purpose. For instance you could have an array of texts that can be selected randomly.

```
String[] strArr = { "text1", "text2", "text3" };
Random rand = new Random();
int selected = rand.nextInt(3);
textView.setText(strArr[selected]);
```

If you **MUST** get the string from other textviews then you can create an array of IDs instead of an array of text. Then use the **Random** object to get an ID and then something like:

```
TextView textToGetString = (TextView) findViewById(idArray[selected]);
String newText = textToGetString.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your thought process seems a little complicated, but there could be a simpler solution.  Ids are really only used by Android as placeholders for an integer.  Instead of randomly generating an id's placeholder, you could populate an integer array with all the ids you want to use and then randomly select one from that array.  Implementation could be as follows in your activity:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[] myTextViews = new int[]{R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3}
int length = myTextViews.length;

TextView tV = (TextView)findViewById(myTextViews[rand.nextInt() % length]);
tV.setText("Whatever Text You Want");
```

I hope this helps!  Good luck